# What is the best way to remove fragment after calling another Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, background-process

I believe I am running into a race condition. From a Fragment, I am starting an Activity, and following that I am removing the Fragment. While the app is kept in the foreground there is no issue with this implementation. However, if right before the Activity starts I put the app into the background, the Activity I am calling will start, however, the fragment is not removed. Here is my code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);

    if (getActivity() != null) {   
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        try {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to implement this? I thought about adding the remove to another thread, but then I receive an exception saying that I cannot perform the remove fragment action before onSavedState. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you adding the fragment in the first activity ? Do you have multiple activities in the first activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getsupportfragmentmanager().popup()

Comment: just popbackstack woth removing.. but do them before starting the another activity...

Comment: I have tried to remove fragment before starting another activity, but then the Activity doesn't start. Remember, things are only going wrong when you quickly put the app in the background. I think that is causing some conflicts. If there is no work around, that is fine. But I have tried re-ordering as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the fragment as removable (through a state instance variable) before starting the new activity. When control gets back to the fragment, just pop the fragment off the stack in your fragment's onResume code, or in your activity's onResume code depending on the state of the fragment. If you are not clear of the idea, let me know. I will write the code sample.